# How to check what the referer url query is?

Tags: php, if-statement, server, query-string, http-referer

lets say I have this $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] output https://example.com/index.php?queryexample=myquery

I want to check if the url query is "queryexample=myquery" and if it's not then the code should say something like "the query is not queryexample=myquery".

I'm aware that I can get the query with ...

```
$URL = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
$query = basename(parse_url($URL, PHP_URL_QUERY));
if(isset($query)) {
echo $query;
}
```

But I want an output only if the query is "queryexample=myquery".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you stuck? You already seem to know how to use `if`

Comment: fyi, you can use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str to parse the query

Answer (score 0):

This may help, to solve your problem:
Check if the array key `queryexample` exists in `$_GET` since the query could include more then your `queryexample`:

```
<?php
if(array_key_exists('queryexample', $_GET)) {
    if($_GET['queryexample'] === 'myquery') {
        echo 'good';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: "queryexample" should be set in `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` though, not in `$_GET`

Comment: thanks, it worked with array_key_exists!